# Shinuy Makom in a parked car

Tags: halacha, blessing, vehicles-transportation

If I make a blessing in my kitchen, I can continue to eat in another part of my house without a new blessing (Mishnah Berurah 178:12 and Be'ur Halacha there).

Let's say I make a blessing in my kitchen (without intent to travel anywhere), and then I go into my garage, and get into my car.  While my car is still in the garage, I can continue eating under the same blessing.  Now let's say I drive my car out of my garage (and travel further than I could see from the location of my original blessing).  Does my blessing continue, since I am in the same car, or have I now changed venues?

What if I said the blessing originally while sitting in my car in my garage(without intent to travel), and then drove off?